# How can I prevent a child element from inheriting a certain style directive from a parent?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a button that is inside a div that has the following styling for a disabled element:

```
.accidentReportingSection [disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

There is one element that I do not want to use that style and it's this button below:

```
<div class="accidentReportingSection">
    <div class="controlSets">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="reportAccident" title="Report Accident">
```

It makes the button disappear from the screen and I don't want that.  I just want it grayed-out and unable to be used when it's disabled.

The issue is, it's in a `scss` file which I don't know what is and I don't have access to.

Is there a way to set this so it doesn't inherit this one style?

thanks!

Comment: if you are unable to remove the current style, just override it with a more specific style

Comment: @Pete thanks, is there a way to do that outside of the `scss` style? I unfortunately do not have access to the `scss`.

Comment: create your own stylesheet and include that

Comment: if you can't use stylesheet add in html style tag or use inline css

Comment: @Pete but what would override the `[disabled]` tag part of `display: none`, would I use `.reportAccident [disabled] {
    display: inline;
}` ?

Comment: `.reportAccident .controlSets [disabled] { display:inline-block; }` I would probably use `inline-block` rather than inline so you can keep any dimensions and padding set on the button

Comment: @Nisha how would use use the `[disabled]` tag in inline css?  I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: So why you use `display: none`, it make parent element disappear, even the child is not inherit this attribute, but also disappear, because it's parent is disappear.